# How do I get mixins in one SCSS to get recognized in all SCSS files in a Rails project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm working with SCSS files in a Ruby on Rails 4.0 web app.

One SCSS file has all my mixins and variables defined, and another SCSS file needs to access those mixins/variables.

```
/*** main.css.scss ***/
$brandfont: 'Rokkitt';
@mixin dropdown_bottom() {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

/*** header.css.scss ***/
header {
  .navbar-brand {
    background:url('/assets/header-icon.png') 15px 7px no-repeat;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:$brandfont;
    @include dropdown_bottom();
  }
}
```

What's the best way to do this?  Do I need to put an "@import" statement in the "header.css.scss" file?  Or do I need to put some kind of "require" statement in the "application.css" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a css file that compiles all your other css files together into one big css document.

Heres a sample of my all.css.scss from a project I work on

```
// CSS Reset
@import "reset.scss";

// Core
@import "variables.scss";
@import "mixins.scss";

// Grid system and page structure
@import "scaffolding.scss";

// Styled patterns and elements
@import "type.scss";
@import "forms.scss";
@import "tables.scss";
@import "patterns.scss";
```

This will get you started but ideally you wouldn't keep all your css files in one big heap like this. Consider creating subdirectories for your base styles, colors, views, menus etc...

The @import method uses standard directory naming protocol so you can specify subdirectories with /'s and ../'s to go back etc...

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt, you'll need to include all your required files in order to use the variables & mixins you've defined

Here's how we do it:

```
#app/assets/sytlesheets.css.scss
@import 'variables';
@import 'the other file you need';
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything my answer doesn't have

Comment: I was writing it when yours was posted, so I figured I just post mine too

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who responded!

I figured out that I should put all of my universal variables and mixins into one file, "main.css.scss", and then have every individual scss file that uses these mixins/vars import that file.

```
/*** main.css.scss ***/
$brandfont: 'Rokkitt';
@mixin dropdown_bottom() {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

/*** header.css.scss ***/
@import "main.css.scss";   // this is the line I need to put in here
header {
  .navbar-brand {
    background:url('/assets/header-icon.png') 15px 7px no-repeat;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:$brandfont;
    @include dropdown_bottom();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. The way in other two answers is the way to go.

Comment: You've made it working in header.css, then how about footer? How about other parts? Should they import the the same file?

Comment: OK, thank you for clarifying.  Yeah, my approach would have been to put "@import 'main.css.css'" in every file that would require it.  But you're right that doing it the way David and Rich both suggested would save me keystrokes.

Comment: Yes, you may neglect CSS is Cascading :) Everything you wrote before is automatically available and override-able later.